# Populating a field in wpf

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, data-binding

I have a database of finance info and i want to check that supplied totals 'add up'.  I have added fields to the database for the check data and am using data binding via the Entity Framework. How do i populate these 'check' fields while the user is adding data to the record?

Eg The form contains SubtotalA, SubtotalB and TotalAB textboxes.  The database has these fields plus CheckTotalAB.  The user keys in `SubtotalA`, `SubtotalB` and `TotalAB` from a hard copy form.  I want to populate `CheckTotalAB` with the sum of `SubtotalA` and `SubtotalB` to compare against the provided `TotalAB`.

I first tried getting the data from the textboxes.  Unfortunately `txtSubtotalA.Value` doesn't exist.

I then thought I'd have to go to the entity itself.  Unfortunately I don't know how to access the current record/entity being entered and if I did, how would I access the value of fields that haven't been saved yet.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

tia 
mcalex

Comment: Create a calculated, not-mapped, property (A + B) in your entity class and only commit when it is equal to `TotalAB`.

Comment: @Gert The field may not ever equal TotalAB, which is why we do the data entry.  if clients totals don't match the totals we calculate, we send a report indicating the difference with a 'please explain'.  Either way, i still can't get to the current SubtotalA & SubtotalB data items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing the entity was the answer.  This was accomplished through use of an entity property in the datacontext that i set to equal a class member i added to  my form class.

After that getting to the entity's fields including my calculated fields was just a case of getting/setting the member's properties.